# Under what conditions on the set $A$ is this statement true:$\forall B \subset A$ $\inf B = \min B$ and $\sup B = \max B$?

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to solve a question from the practice problem set our professor gave us. The problem goes like this.

> Given a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $A \neq \emptyset$ what conditions must be met when constructing $A$ so that $\forall B \subset A$, $B\neq \emptyset$ we have $\inf B = \min B$ and $\sup B = \max B$ ?

My gut instinct tells me $A$ must be a countable set so that any subset would include its $\sup$ and $\inf$ am I right?

Comment: As soon as $|A|=\infty$ you can construct some sequence with elements in $A$ without a limit in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countability isn't enough. (Consider $\Bbb Q,$ for example.)

Note that if you have any infinite set $A$ of reals, then there exists a strictly monotone sequence of points of $A$. (Why?) Considering the set $B$ of points of that sequence, we have that $B\subseteq A,$ but either $B$ has no maximum or has no minimum.

What, then, can we conclude is a condition that $A$ *must* satisfy in order to have the desired property? Is this condition enough, or are more conditions needed?